# Get the name of an added table

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm having an issue to get the name of a table I created.

Here's my simplified code:

```
var mytable = mysheet.tables.add(mysheet.getUsedRange(), true);

...

mytable.load('name');

return context.sync()
    .then(function () {

            mytable.name;

    });
```

I don't want to give the table a name (since it might already exist in the workbook), so I let Excel give it a name.

But after the sync I always get the error:
"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot read property 'name'... please call "context.sync()"...
(sorry, I only get the German error-message - so, this is a translated text).

Interesting aspect: This error only raises in completely new workbooks (Excel online). If I use a workbook I already created a table using the above way it works perfectly without any error.

What do I do wrong? Do I have to load something different than "name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with the following code, and it worked just fine on both Desktop and Office Online:

```
Excel.run(function (context) {
    let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var mytable = sheet.tables.add(sheet.getUsedRange(), true);

    mytable.load('name');

    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            console.log(mytable.name);
        });
});
```

If you're still having issues, could you post your full code -- ideally in the form of a [Script Lab snippet](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/README.md#import)?

Comment: This is strange, Michael. :)
While I did exactly this before and always received an error, it now works like a charm.
OK... you better tell me you changed something globally on the Excel configuration to ensure it's working now, right? :D

Comment: @E.Haas, I am not sure what exactly about your code was different -- but certainly, the PropertyNotLoaded error has a way of sneaking up on people.  FWIW, I have written a book, with [all profits to charity](http://buildingofficeaddins.com/charity), about Office.js, where I dedicate a chapter to it:  "7.4 Understanding the PropertyNotLoaded error".  See the book, "[Building Office Add-ins using Office.js](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins/)" on Leanpub:  https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins/

Comment: Zlatkovsky: Thx a bunch for your support and even for pointing at your book.
But I already managed it to make it work.
My new app is currently under review... hope it's going to be accepted.
If you want, you may take a look at it and let me know, what you think (but if so, please be honest!).
It was - obviously - just some sort of an error between my ears ;)
But anyway, I'll maybe have a look into it, if the next issue appears.